# Running a Program over a certain number of columns and rows

Tags: excel, vba

Problem with getting the program to run as I would like it to, I have managed to get the hole column to work but i need all 12 rows to work the rows stars at 20 so "T2" and skip a column next one is 22 so "V2"... all the way to "AP2". 
The point in this program is to enter stock in the entry column and adding it with the current stock then the entry column becomes empty.

```
   Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
     If target.Column = 20 And target.Value > 0 Then
     Dim val As Double
   val = target.Value
     target.Value = 0
        Cells(target.Row, target.Column - 1).Value = val + Cells(target.Row, target.Column - 1).Value
   End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: not sure I understand your Q, but try to change `If target.Column = 20 And target.Value > 0 Then` to `If Not Intersect(Target,Range("T2:T14")) Is Nothing And target.Value > 0 Then` and change `"T2:T14"` to desired address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interesting approach. Try this...

The step by step processing of areas / columns of area / single cells will support copy+paste of several values in one step, copy copying from one cell into several other cells in one step.

The Application.EnableEvents statement prevents the event from firing itselfes.

Good luck! :-)

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim rngArea As Range, rngColumn As Range, rngSingleCell As Range
    Dim lngColumn As Long
    Dim dblVal As Double
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'loop though all changed areas
    For Each rngArea In target
        'loop though all changed columns of this area
        For Each rngColumn In rngArea
            'check if column number shall be processed, i.e. is 20 / 22 / 24 ... 42
            lngColumn = rngColumn.Column
            If ((lngColumn >= 20) And (lngColumn <= 42) And ((lngColumn Mod 2) = 0)) Then
                'loop though all changed cells of this column of this area
                For Each rngSingleCell In rngColumn
                    If rngSingleCell.Value > 0 Then
                        dblVal = rngSingleCell.Value
                        rngSingleCell.Value = 0
                        Cells(rngSingleCell.Row, rngSingleCell.Column - 1).Value = dblVal + Cells(rngSingleCell.Row, rngSingleCell.Column - 1).Value
                        End If
                    Next rngSingleCell
                End If
            Next rngColumn
        Next rngArea
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Regards,
Kawi42